# MySQL Multiple Joins in one query

Tags: mysql, join

I have this query:

```
SELECT L.Season, L.Team, L.Position, L.Round, 
        SUM(M.WL LIKE '%W') AS Won,
        SUM(M.WL LIKE '%L') AS Lost,
        SUM(M.WL = 'D') AS Drawn,
        F.Position,
        P.PlayerID, P.Surname, P.FirstName, SUM(P.Goals) AS G
FROM `LadderPositions` AS L
INNER JOIN RoundsPerSeason AS R ON R.Rounds = L.Round AND R.Season = L.Season
INNER JOIN MatchDetails AS M ON L.Season=.M.Season AND L.Team=M.Team
INNER JOIN FinalPositions AS F ON L.Season=.F.Season AND L.Team=F.Team
INNER JOIN PlayerDetails AS P ON L.Season=.P.Season AND L.Team=P.Team
WHERE L.Team = '$Team'
GROUP BY Season
```

I am trying to create a season summary which will display the season, ladder position before finals, ladder position after finals, Games Won, Lost and Drawn followed by the player who kicked the most goals and the number of goals they kicked for each season for a particular team.

I have the output I need from the LadderPositions and FinalPositions table but I am not getting the correct output from the MatchDetails or PlayerDetails table.

Here's a sample of my output...

```
Season|Team|Position|Round|Won|Lost|Drawn|Position|PlayerID|Surname|FirstName|G
1934|ABC|7||21|2786|5572|0|7|387|BEE|Henry George (Judda)|5355
```

If I remove the INNER JOIN to PlayerDetails the Win-Loss figure is correct 7-14 but adding the INNER JOIN to PlayerDetails outputs the Win-Loss as 2786-5572.

The PlayerDetails is returning the first player in the team list for each year, not the player with the most goals and the sum of goals is also not correct- the most goals by a player in this example should be 45 and its a different player than the one output.

The query is also taking around 18 seconds to execute.

Comment: In general, if you select a column (like round), but don't then include that column in the GROUP BY, then the result is going to be fairly nonsensical. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: You are grouping by season so everything else is going to be 'indeterminate' - it would help if you could add sample data as text to the question together with expected result.